# My title container div width is interferring with a navigation div

Tags: html, css

My title containers width is set to 960px, but it's interfering with my navigation bar div by taking up a whole line and not letting the nav bar div go all the way to the top.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: ;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
  background-color: #34495e;
}
.container {
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 2000px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
.h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
.sidebar {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed, 0px 0 0px 0px;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #333;
  z-index: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sidebar li {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <h1 class="h1">Nicholas Peppas</h1>
    <hr color="black" width="260px">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="sidebar">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>About Nick!</li>
    <li>Services</li>
    <li>Contact Nick!</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/NicholasPeppas/pen/grqXyk)

Comment: what is "tile container"?

Comment: You can apply position `absolute` or `fixed` with `top: 0; left: 0` to your navigation container.

Answer (score 0):

may be this is what you need

```css
.sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```